# View /page.jsf could not be restored

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, session-timeout

I have problem which I cannot solve. When I refresh opened JSF page after the page is idle for example 10 minutes I get this error message:

```
serverError: class javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException viewId:/page.jsf - View /page.jsf could not be restored.
```

How I can increase the JSF View time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set your session timeout parameter to 45 minute in web.xml like this

```
<session-config> 
   <session-timeout>45</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

also you can easily handle this exception in a seperate page by adding following code to your web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/exception/sessionexpired.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: Is it possible to force a full refresh of the page when this happens?